# Online365: CSR does not work for Calendar Forms?

Tags: calendar, form, client-side-rendering

subj

no workarounds?

```
"use strict";

var defaultSubtypeLookupFieldTemplate = SPClientTemplates._defaultTemplates.Fields.default.all.all.Lookup.NewForm;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    // ..
});
```

On calendar NewForm.aspx get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **SPClientTemplates is not defined**

Tried to wrap with this code, looks like it does not apply(no results, no errors):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

var defaultSubtypeLookupFieldTemplate = SPClientTemplates._defaultTemplates.Fields.default.all.all.Lookup.NewForm;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    // ..
});
}, 'ClientTemplates.js');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The JSLink property is not supported on Survey or Events lists. A
>   SharePoint calendar is an Events list.

So there is no OOTB way to attach CSR js code with calendar list. For a workaround, you can create your own jQuery or vanilla javascript code and add it on the page by adding the reference in Content Editor Webpart/Script Editor webpart on that page.

Reference -  [Customize a list view in SharePoint Add-ins using client-side rendering](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/customize-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-add-ins-using-client-side-rendering)

You can also checkout [SPUtility.js](https://sputility.codeplex.com/) or [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/). They are quite decent and well documented.